# cmake files for projects structure where child c++ classes inherits parents classes

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I have c++ project  with structure like this:

```
src
|    CMakeLists.txt     (?)
|
└─── project
    |   base_0.hpp
    │   base_0.cpp   (defines Base_0 class)
    │
    └───folder_1
    │   │   base_1.cpp 
    │   │   base_1.hpp  (defines Base_1 class, which inharits Base_0 class)
    │   │
    │   └───subfolder_1
    │       │   base_2.cpp 
    │       │   base_2.hpp (defines Base_2 class, which inharits Base_1 class)
    │       │   ...
    │   
    └───folder_2
        │   base_12.cpp
        │   base_12.hpp
```

I have no idea how to build a project with such structure, anywhere I read about it there was written about the simplest structure

I tried with CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(lib_project VERSION 0.0.1)


set(LIBRARY_HEADERS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project/base_0.hpp

    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project/folder_1/base_1.hpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project/folder_1/subfolder_1/base_2.hpp
)


set(LIBRARY_SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project/base_0.cpp

    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project/folder_1/base_1.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project/folder_1/subfolder_1/base_2.cpp
)

set(ALL_FILES ${LIBRARY_HEADERS} ${LIBRARY_SOURCES})

add_library(library STATIC ${ALL_FILES})


set_target_properties(
    library PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 14
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
target_include_directories(
    library
    PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

install(
    TARGETS library EXPORT libraryTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

install(
    FILES ${ALL_HEADER_FILES} DESTINATION include
)

install(
    EXPORT libraryTargets
    FILE libraryConfig.cmake 
    NAMESPACE Library::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/library  
)
```

I read about subdirectories in CMake, but I think it's not applied for this structure.

Comment: Does the code you tried work? Otherwise, which error it shows? "I read about subdirectories in CMake, but I think it's not applied for this structure." - Subdirectories in CMake are usable in most cases. Why don't you want to try them?

Comment: I use 1 CMakeLists.txt per target where a target is a library or executable. I sometimes have extra CMakeLists.txt if I have a hierarchy of folders and glob the subfolders. This occurs mostly for testing projects where I have dozens to hundreds of small 1 cpp executables that test some new topic I am learning.

Comment: CMake subdirectories are great, as the two commands before me already said. What's definitely wrong in your case is the target_include_directories command. You have to specify the folders which you want to include here, for example project/folder_1/subfolder_1/. Including ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} should have no effect here. Also when the header files are the interface of your library you should consider using the Keyword PUBLIC instead of PRIVATE.